# Help with deducing roots for cubics

Tags: cubics

$f(x) = 2x^3 - 5x^2 + 7x + 10$

Given that $2x - 3$ is a factor, solve $f(x) = 0$ completely.

I have tried using a division of polynomials method to give a quadratic, but this gave a remainder of $16$. I have also used online calculators which suggest that there is no simple solution. Is there an error or should I be using a different method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but $2x-3$ is not a factor of $f(x)$

Comment: The solutions are not trivial and $2x-3$ is not a factor (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*x%5E3%E2%88%925*x%5E2%2B7*x%2B10%3D0). You can use Cardano's formula to determine the solutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

Comment: There's an error.  If $2x-3$ is a factor, then $3/2$ is a root.  If you plug $3/2$ into the polynomial, you won't get $0$.

Comment: have you checked that 3/2  is a root

Comment: $2x-3$ cannot be a factor, if it were than at $x=0$ we would have $3$ as a divisor of $10$ :-( .

Comment: the only real factor is $$\frac 1 6 \left(5 - \frac{17}{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{59\ 757} - 730}} + \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{59\ 757} - 730}\right) $$

Comment: Since $f\in \mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and also in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ by Gauß-Lemma, thus all roots are complex with at least one real root by the mean value theorem. If you want to solve $f(x)=0$, you can apply Cardano's method.

Comment: I suspect there is an error somewhere. Maybe in copying the problem to MSE or in the source document containing the problem.

Comment: $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x) = 2x^3 - 5x^2 - 7x + 10$. The quotient $\frac{2x^3 - 5x^2 + 7x + 10}{x-1}=2x^2-3x-10$ is somewhat similar to the alleged factor ($2x-3$) in the problem. Maybe the problem source document author lost their train of thought or something while writing the problem.

Comment: Try with $2 x^3-5 x^2+7 x-6=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we put $x=\frac 32$ into $f(x)$ then we can see that \begin{align}f\left(\frac 32\right)&=2\left(\frac 32\right)^3−5\left(\frac 32\right)^2+7\left(\frac 32\right)+10\\
&=\frac {27}4-\frac {45}4+\frac{21}2+10\\
&=16\neq 0\end{align}

As $f\left(\frac 32\right)$ is not equal to $0$, then $2x-3$ is not a root.

This appears to be a homework/exam style question, are you sure you've written down $f(x)$ correctly? Either that, or the person who wrote the question mis-wrote $f(x)$ in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like many users in the comments I have entered the question into Wolfram Alpha and it did indeed give two complex roots and one real root, albeit not the $\frac{3}{2}$ that would be suggested by using factor theorem if the source question had been correct. It does look like the source question was flawed. Thanks for all the support.

[Link to Wolfram Alpha solution page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202x3%E2%88%925x2%2B7x%2B10)

[image: exact]

[image: APPROXIMATE]